# Query shows me duplicate values

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following query and it gives me duplicate values, that is, the 2500 of the result column should appear only once but it duplicates the result, why?

```
select sum(Importe) as Nuevo,
    (SELECT SUM(e.importe) 
    FROM ext a 
    WHERE (a.stat = 14 OR  a.stat = 15) AND a.cvl_cliente = rmc.code
    GROUP BY rmc.num  ) AS result 
FROM red rmc   
where rmc.code='7934628'  
group by num
```

| Nuevo | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2500 |
| 100 | 2500 |

separate:

SELECT SUM(e.importe)
FROM ext a
WHERE (a.stat = 14 OR  a.stat = 15) AND a.cvl_cliente =rmc.code GROUP BY rmc.num

| a |
| --- |
| 2500 |

select sum(Importe) as Nuevo FROM red rmc where rmc.code='7934628' group by num

| Nuevo |
| --- |
| 2000 |
| 100 |

I understand that separately a query returns a result and in the other two results, but why is it duplicated and does not show null?

Comment: Where is `num`? Post the data source.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: num is in rmc, rmc is red

Comment: I mean you didn't show it in `SELECT`. Run both queries separately with added `num` column and paste the result into your question, for example `SELECT num, SUM(e.importe) ..`. It's strage to me that you `GROUP BY num` but you didn't show the `num` column in `SELECT`.. therefore you're _assuming_ that it should only show once.

Comment: To make it easier, copy and paste the source data that returns this result to you.

Comment: Where does `SUM(e.importe)` comes from? Your code doesn't have any table with that alias `e`.

Comment: Sorry is SELECT SUM(a.importe) FROM ext a WHERE (a.stat = 14 OR a.stat = 15) AND a.cvl_cliente =rmc.code GROUP BY rmc.num

Comment: Check if this fiddle is anything close to your data source. If not, update it accordingly and click "Run", that will generate a new link and you can paste that link into your question.  https://dbfiddle.uk/R0g_pj5o

Comment: It is perfect! @FanoFN

Comment: The problem is the values 2500 duplicate

Comment: According to your query and that data sample it is not a duplicate. If it is not supposed to be a duplicate, then where should it be shown?